# CoreFoundation get value for key in CFDictionaryRef

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-foundation

I have this function

```
valueForKey(CFDictionaryRef dict, CFStringRef key) {
    CFTypeRef valueX = CFSTR("key not found");
    NSDictionary *settings = (__bridge NSDictionary *)dict;
    NSString *keyString = (__bridge NSString *)key;
    NSLog(@"valueForKey: %@ inDict: %@ value: %@",keyString,settings,settings[keyString]);
    NSLog(@"allKeys: %@ allValues: %@",settings.allKeys,settings.allValues);

    if (CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent(dict, key, &valueX)) {
        NSLog(@"CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent: %@",valueX);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent not found");
    }
}
```

valueX prints out "key not found"

it basically gets a value for a key from a dictionary. (I wanted to do this in a separate function, so I don't have that much code duplication).

Here is the output when the function is called:

```
valueForKey: kEnabled inDict: {
                kEnabled = 1;   
        } value: (null)  allKeys: (
         kEnabled   
        ) allValues: (
                        1   
        )  CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent not found
```

so the key is obviously in the dictionary, but getting the value for the key returns NULL. really weird.

So I made a little test: on the top of the function I inserted

```
key = CFSTR("kEnabled");
```

so I hardcoded the key and overwrote the parameter (which somehow cannot be found in the dictionary). and this worked, I got the value out of the dictionary.

Here is how I create the original parameter string:

```
CFStringRef key = (__bridge CFStringRef)[myObject identifier];
```

and pass it to the function.

Does anybody have a clue what's wrong with this?

Comment: I'm no expert, but it seems to me that the documentation on CFDictionaryGetValueIfPresent might provide some food for thought: "The key hash and equal callbacks provided when the dictionary was created are used to compare. If the hash callback was NULL, key is treated as a pointer and converted to an integer. If the equal callback was NULL, pointer equality (in C, ==) is used. If key, or any of the keys in theDict, is not understood by the equal callback, the behavior is undefined." So by default NSString `isEqual:` is _not_ being used; the strings would need to be _object-identical_.

Comment: thanks! adding &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks to my dictionary creation fixed it!

Comment: Awesome. Well done.